# Emgu.CV.CvInvoke threw an exception

Tags: .net, dll, opencv, emgucv

Im using emgu in my project.

I get this exceptit:
[image]

Here the details of the exception:
[image]

The opencv_core242 is in the folder project,and platform target set to x86.

Any idea what might cause the exception and how to solve it?

Comment: Put opencv_core242 inside BIN folder....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on cvextern.dll to see if opencv_core242.dll is depending on another dll like nvcuda.dll or if you have a 32/64-bits mismatch.

Take a look at this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594993/emgucv-nvcuda-dll-could-not-be-found).

Answer (score 0):

In .../windows/system32 I pasted cudart32_42_9.dll file.It's helped me to fix me problem