# Unable to run Emgu CV

Tags: c#, emgucv

I started learning C# because I wanted to work on computer vision using Emgu CV, but when I installed  try to run a test program  with VS 2012 Ultimate, I get the error in the image below.

It runs well for ordinary c# programs. I have tried all I know, I have even reinstalled Emgu CV, four times and my visual studio as well.

[image: Visual studio Error Message]

Comment: possible duplicate of [EmguCV - nvcuda.dll could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594993/emgucv-nvcuda-dll-could-not-be-found)

Comment: okay just seeing it. Thanks

Comment: Which version of Emgu CV are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have a nVidia graphics card with CUDA support (nvcuda.dll, nv = nvidia, cuda = cuda)
and I got the impression that it is not possible to use emgucv then.
read this for more information [EmguCV - nvcuda.dll could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594993/emgucv-nvcuda-dll-could-not-be-found) (answer 1).

Comment: does it mean I would never be able to run emgucv on my system?

Comment: Only if you buy a nvidia with cuda. As far as i recall, some calculations from emgucv applications are given to the graphics card. thats why the graphics card needs cuda. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA

Comment: It works without an Nvidia card too. I think it should work as long as you avoid using anything from the Emgu.CV.GPU namespace...

Comment: Actually I think my answer (answer 2) for [EmguCV - nvcuda.dll could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594993/emgucv-nvcuda-dll-could-not-be-found) is a better solution. No need to buy a NVidia card...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember from when I downloaded EmguCV, When you download V 3.0 (I dont see why you would want to use a previous version) you are given the option to download with or without CUDA acceleration. https://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/files/emgucv/3.0.0-alpha/
The problem you are encountering is possibly a result of installing the CUDA package. . [These are the download options from SourceForge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqOV8.png)