# read a PNG image using emgu Image

Tags: c#, emgucv

After saving a image in PNG format using

`bitmap.save(filename, ImageFormat.PNG)`,

I now try to read the same image

`Image<Rgb, Byte> inpImage = new Image<Rgb, Byte>(dir + fn_only + "_ms.png")` using emgu Image. On runtime I get a

> System.TypeInitializationException occurred in Emgu.CV.dll

Exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke'
>   threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'opencv
>   _core242': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8
>   007007E)
>      at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvRedirectError(CvErrorCallback errorHandler, IntPtr user
>   data, IntPtr prevUserdata)
>      at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Emgu.CV.Image`2..ctor(String fileName)

when opencv_242 is present. On dependency check it says NVCUDA is missing. I do not have a GPU, obv there wont be NVCUDA in that case.

I tried color type RGB and BGR.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EmguCV TypeInitializationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369684/emgucv-typeinitializationexception)

Comment: If it's an NVCUDA issue, then you should read my answer to this question (not the approved answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594993/emgucv-nvcuda-dll-could-not-be-found/12613872#12613872. By the way, you DO have a GPU, it's only not an Nvidia GPU.

Answer (score 2):

```
//a way is first open the PNG in a bitmap

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(dir + fn_only + "_ms.png");

//and read the bitman how image

Image<Rgb, Byte> inpImage = new Image<Rgb, Byte>(bitmap);
```

ref: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images 
Creating image from Bitmap